# org-mode spreadsheet formula, can one use the result of org-babel block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm trying to find a way to use the output of existing org-babel block in org-mode spreadsheet formulae without rewriting them in emacs-lisp.
Is it possible?

TBLFM line is pseudo code, it is syntactically invalid.

```org
#+NAME: currencyRateOnDate
#+BEGIN_SRC http :pretty :select .[0].rate
GET https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?valcode=USD&date=${date}&json
#+END_SRC


| Name |     Date | Currency rate |
|------+----------+---------------|
| Foo  | 20210125 |               |
#+TBLFM: $3=currencyRateOnDate(date=$2)


#+CALL: currencyRateOnDate(date="20210714")

#+RESULTS:
: 27.3216
```

or alternatively, is it possible to wrap existing org-babel blocks(e.g. in http, ruby "languages") as emacs-lisp wrapped blocks(which could be easily called in org-mode spreadsheet formula)?

Comment: This might read more clearly if you presented the block before the table.

Comment: @PhilHudson sounds right. Just switched the order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quite a bit of fighting trying to create a wrapper emacs-lisp function I found the `org-sbe` macro that solves this exact problem.

To make it work, I've changed TBLFM definition to the following:

```
#+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe "currencyRateOnDate" (date $2))'
```

org-sbe macro docs:

> org-sbe
> org-sbe is a Lisp macro in `ob-table.el'.
>
> (org-sbe SOURCE-BLOCK &rest VARIABLES)
>
> Return the results of calling SOURCE-BLOCK with VARIABLES.
> Each element of VARIABLES should be a two
> element list, whose first element is the name of the variable and
> second element is a string of its value. The following call to
> `org-sbe' would be equivalent to the following source code block.
>
> (org-sbe 'source-block (n $2) (m 3))
>
> #+begin_src emacs-lisp :var results=source-block(n=val_at_col_2, m=3) :results silent
> results
> #+end_src
>
> NOTE: by default string variable names are interpreted as
> references to source-code blocks, to force interpretation of a
> cell's value as a string, prefix the identifier a "$" (e.g.,
> "$$2" instead of "$2" or "$@2$2" instead of "@2$2").
>
> NOTE: it is also possible to pass header arguments to the code
> block. In this case a table cell should hold the string value of
> the header argument which can then be passed before all variables
> as shown in the example below.
>
> | 1 | 2 | :file nothing.png | nothing.png |
> #+TBLFM: @1$4='(org-sbe test-sbe $3 (x $1) (y $2))