# How to execute parameterized src block via elisp and get result?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a src block to get a value from some table:

```
#+NAME: ref
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var  name="" table=main
(let ((key (if (symbolp name) (symbol-name name) name)))
  (nth 2 (assoc key table)))
#+END_SRC
```

In Org I can execute this by:

```
#+CALL: ref("value")
```

How can I do the same only in Lisp?

I tried this:

```lisp
(defun a/ref (params)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (org-babel-goto-named-src-block "ref")
    (org-babel-execute-src-block nil nil params) 
    (org-babel-read-result)))

(a/ref '(("value")))
```

But it didn't work

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [org-mode spreadsheet formula, can one use the result of org-babel block?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66734/org-mode-spreadsheet-formula-can-one-use-the-result-of-org-babel-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is related to the library of babel. In this example, I construct something similar to the babel-call org element and use it to get the info needed for `org-babel-execute-src-block` to execute it with the argument.

```
#+name: main
| x     | 1 | a |
| value | 2 | b |

#+NAME: ref
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :var  name="" table=main
(let ((key (if (symbolp name) (symbol-name name) name)))
  (nth 2 (assoc key table)))
#+END_SRC

#+call: ref("value")

#+RESULTS:
: b

The equivalent in elisp is:

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(org-babel-execute-src-block nil (org-babel-lob-get-info '(babel-call (:call "ref" :arguments "\"value\""))))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: b
```